# Topshelf Compatibility with .NET Framework 4.8 - Seeking Guidance

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services, .net-4.8, topshelf

All,
I currently have a .NET Framework 4.7.2-based application running as a Windows service using Topshelf. I'm planning an upgrade to .NET Framework 4.8. However, I'm concerned about the fact that Topshelf is not actively maintained.

Considering Topshelf is no longer actively maintained, are there any risks or drawbacks that I should be aware of especially with .net framework 4.8?

Thanks.